# Why are my sprinkles floating and not sticking to the mesh?

Tags: particles

Can somebody help me on why my sprinkles are floating when i do a hair particle thingy. I did the particle properties and I'm trying to add some sprinkles. When I tried adding them as an objects, they all started floating. The scale, instead of changing the size of the sprinkles, they also change the distances of each sprinkle. What can I do so the sprinkles stay on the surface so they don't float around and so that they don't go further apart?

Comment: um, this question is very unclear.  You need to elaborate a lot more if you want help

Comment: @ETHANDAY, do you understand it now?

Comment: that's better yes

Comment: could you share your file with me so I can take a closer look?  you can use this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=vyaW7d3d" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/vyaW7d3d/) @ETHANDAY

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that the origin of your sprinkle object was very far away from the actual mesh.  That is why your sprinkles are all floating above the doughnut.

All you need to do is select your sprinkle object, right click, go to *Set Origin* and then click *Origin to Geometry*.

[image]

After that, your sprinkles should show up on the surface of your doughnut.

Comment: eyyy, thx so much man :D

Comment: no problem.  could you mark my answer as accepted so other people know that this problem has been solved?

Comment: @user110589 Hello and welcome. Please don't add thank you as a comment , upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted